# Delphi component similar to Outlook's to display attachments

Tags: delphi

Is there a Delphi component similar to the one Outlook uses
to show the attachments ?

[image: attachments]

I'm D2006. So I'm not familiar 
with any of the new Delphi 
components yet.

Thanks !

Comment: I think ListView might be the way to go. Not as elegant as Outlook's though.

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish this without a workaround (drawing it by your self or using a TListView).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a ListView:

[image: ListView picture]

Here's the DFM for the ListView:

```
object ListView1: TListView
  Left = 8
  Top = 8
  Width = 380
  Height = 28
  BorderWidth = 4
  Columns = <>
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = [fsUnderline]
  Items.ItemData = {
    0376000000020000000500000001000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF000000
    00104C006F0067006F002E0067006900660020002800310020004B0042002900
    3B000500000005000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF000000001147006C006F
    00620065002E0067006900660020002800360020004B00420029003B00}
  ParentFont = False
  SmallImages = ImageList1
  TabOrder = 0
  ViewStyle = vsList
end
```

Comment: And to complete this with the best feature Outlook offers with that bar, add drap & drop functionality: [The Drag and Drop Component Suite for Delphi](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/).